# Django administration

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm, django-admin

Интегрировал в Django имеющуюся БД MySQL как показано здесь: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/. Далее зарегистрировал модель в admin.py, в Django administration эту модель не увидел, решил зарегистрировать все таблицы всё осталось прежним, также ничего не произошло. В чём может быть проблема? 
**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
class Actor(models.Model):
    actor_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'actor'


class Address(models.Model):
    address_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', models.DO_NOTHING)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'address'


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'


class City(models.Model):
    city_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city'


class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'country'


class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', models.DO_NOTHING)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, models.DO_NOTHING)
    active = models.IntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer'


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_session'


class Film(models.Model):
    film_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    release_year = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', models.DO_NOTHING)
    original_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    rental_duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rental_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    length = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    replacement_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    special_features = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'film'


class FilmActor(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'film_actor'
        unique_together = (('actor', 'film'),)


class FilmCategory(models.Model):
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'film_category'
        unique_together = (('film', 'category'),)


class FilmText(models.Model):
    film_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'film_text'


class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, models.DO_NOTHING)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'inventory'


class Language(models.Model):
    language_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'language'


class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.DO_NOTHING)
    staff = models.ForeignKey('Staff', models.DO_NOTHING)
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'payment'


class Rental(models.Model):
    rental_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rental_date = models.DateTimeField()
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, models.DO_NOTHING)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.DO_NOTHING)
    return_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    staff = models.ForeignKey('Staff', models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rental'
        unique_together = (('rental_date', 'inventory', 'customer'),)


class Staff(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, models.DO_NOTHING)
    picture = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', models.DO_NOTHING)
    active = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'staff'


class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manager_staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'store'
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from example.models import Actor, Address, AuthGroup, AuthGroupPermissions, AuthPermission, AuthUser, AuthUserGroups, \
    AuthUserUserPermissions, Category, City, Country, Customer, DjangoAdminLog, DjangoContentType, DjangoMigrations, \
    DjangoSession, Film, FilmActor, FilmCategory, FilmText, Inventory, Language, Payment, Rental, Staff, Store


admin.site.register(
    [Actor,
     Address,
     AuthGroup,
     AuthGroupPermissions,
     AuthPermission,
     AuthUser,
     AuthUserGroups,
     AuthUserUserPermissions,
     Category,
     City,
     Country,
     Customer,
     DjangoAdminLog,
     DjangoContentType,
     DjangoMigrations,
     DjangoSession,
     Film,
     FilmActor,
     FilmCategory,
     FilmText,
     Inventory,
     Language,
     Payment,
     Rental,
     Staff,
     Store, ])
```

Прописал приложение task1, там по умолчанию находится файл admin.py, models.py после выполнения действий описанных здесь https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/ появился в самой корневой папке (смотрите картинку ниже)

**settings.py:**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'r34p#5pil27#t+mc1p(2vh5-a9zn^rdsdk$w9a(h08oem-pie^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'task1',
    'task1.admin',
    'models',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sakila',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

[image: Папка с проектом]

Comment: admin.py где расположен? Рядом с models.py?

Comment: @andreymal, нет. Добавил рядом с models.py, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Приложение, в котором лежат models.py и admin.py, прописано в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Очень странно, что у вас models.py не находится ни в каком Django-приложении (а наверно должно лежать внутри task1 например)

Comment: @andreymal, если честно models.py там был, но он был пуст. Но после выполнения этой команды `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. Создался новый models.py. А  models.py в task1 так и остался пустым. В итоге от безысходности я его удалил пробовал, вместо него ставить models.py с таблицами, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: Вы соблюдали все три условия одновременно? Непустой `task1/models.py`, рабочий `task1/admin.py` с правильным импортом `from task1.models` и прописывание `task1`в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @andreymal после того как я изменил INSTALLED_APPS и прописал всё(смотрите выше settings.py), появляется следующая ошибка "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Comment: С очень высокой вероятностью это вы где-то накосячили, не разобравшись в устройстве джанги — исправляйте то место в коде, в котором эта ошибка появляется